# Correlation coefficient with X>2

Tags: correlation

Obtain the correlation coefficient for the random variables $X$ and $Y$ having joint density $f(x,y) = \frac{16y}{x^3}$ for $x \gt 2$ and $0 \lt y \lt 1$.

I know this is an easy question but I was having trouble setting up my integrals.

For $E(X)$ what should my bounds be? I don't understand how to set up the $X>2$. It's different from the examples I'm used to.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  If this is a homework question, please add the `self-study` tag and read its wiki [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), which includes etiquette on asking such questions, including showing a "good faith" attempt at solving the problem yourself and then showing where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the joint density can be separated into the respective marginal densities. We now have $f(x,y) = \frac{16y}{x^3} = 16y \cdot \frac{1}{x^3} = f(x) \cdot f(y)$. Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have covariance of zero. Now the correlation must be zero.

Comment: So the way I'm use to doing these questions is to solve for E(X), E(Y), etc... and then plug these values in to the equations. My understanding of correlation isn't the best but are you saying because the bounds of X and Y do not intersect there is no correlation so the correlation coefficient is just 0? we do not need to solve for E(X) at all?

Comment: You can solve for $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ and get the same answer but it is much longer. Any time random variables are independent they automatically have no correlation because they have no covariance. Solving the way you are used to would entail finding $f(x) = \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{16y}{x^3} dy$ and $f(y) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{16y}{x^3} dx$. You can then use these to find $E(Y)$ and $E(X)$.

Comment: This answer is correct, but its reasoning overlooks an important subtlety.  In fact, a complete expression of the density is $$f(x,y) = \frac{16 y}{x^3}\mathcal{I}_{(2,\infty)\times(0,1)}(x,y).$$ You cannot neglect the constraints (as represented by the indicator function $\mathcal I$).  Since it also happens to be the case that $$\mathcal{I}_{(2,\infty)\times(0,1)}(x,y)=\mathcal{I}_{(2,\infty)}(x) \mathcal{I}_{(0,1)}(y),$$ the conclusion of independence actually is true. This point seems directly to address the question itself, which is "how to set up [the constraint] $X\gt 2$."